# android setText not working for custom title bar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-titlebar

I have made a custom title bar for my floating activity.
Now I want to change text of TextView in my custom title programmatically, but unable to do so.
I can change text via xml, but i want it to do in code.

here is code of label.java(floating activity) which is not updating textView in titlebar

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

       setContentView(R.layout.my_title);
        TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
        label.setText("Label here code");//not working
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_title);

        setContentView(R.layout.label);// as i need this layout for rest of activity

    //rest of code
```

myTitle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myTitle"
android:text="Label here"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your'e doing it wrong. You have to do it like this:

```
public class CustomTitleActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView title;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.label);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_title);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText("My custom title");
    }
}
```

You were trying to inflate your custom title layout into the content area of your Activity with `setContentView(R.layout.my_title)`, which of course lets you grab the `TextView` because you inflated it into the container, but then you told it to inflate your custom title into the Window, which inflated an entirely different TextView which is actually the one you want. Then you overwrote the content of the Activity with `setContentView(R.layout.label)`.

Comment: well that worked, but i have a bit confusion in understanding why setContentView is used above getWindow().setFeatureInt(....)

Comment: Because setContentView causes all top level views to inflate into your Activity, which includes the container that holds the titlebar. It has to exist before you can change what's in it.